# Swift: PhotoLibrary delete assets and get progress

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, photolibrary, phphotolibrary

I need to show progress of deleting photos and videos from photo library. In case of few photos - deletion can take few seconds but in case of 1000 photos - it will take few minutes. So, i need to show a progress somehow. How can I do that?

My code

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assets as NSFastEnumeration)
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` to, as the name suggests, observe changes to the photo library. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/observing_changes_in_the_photo_library).

When the `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` notices a change, you can then request the details for that change to find out what to do, in this case you'd upload your user interface.

You can read more about `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrarychangeobserver).

EDIT: As a response to the comment stating that this observer doesn't fire often enough for UI state updates, you could try a different approach, like querying all photos periodically (maybe every few seconds on a repeating timer) and then getting the count of the result. Then when the operation (in this case, deleting the items) is finished you can invalidate the timer.

Comment: i tried, for 100 photos to remove, it was called 3 times

Comment: @Haloo see my edited answer, it might be something to look into.